# show a button after the server side condition is met

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

so i have 2 regions in my page and 1 report + 1 button in each region, the buttons allow you to add items to the corresponding report but i can't add any items to the 2nd report unless the first has at least 1 item, that's why i did this to the 2nd button:

```
server-side condition : rows returned
SQL Query: select * from table1
```

i tried to use a dynamic action to refresh the region but it only refreshes the report

Comment: how about the DA checking the condition and Show Button?

Comment: a server side condition is evaluated when the page is rendered. If a component is not rendered because of a server side condition you can't show it with a dynamic action anymore. You can use a dynamic action to show/hide the button.